# Callback if Event is received multiple Times

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm currently writing a node application, that checks if a certain file exists at a specific location. For every order that exists where it is supposed to be I'd like to make a put request to my Woocommerce Api, that changes the order status to Processing.

```
  for (i=0; i<my_orders.length; i++) {
    var exportedThisPdf = true;
    var orderId = my_orders[i].orderId.toString();
    for (p=0; p<my_orders[i].products.length; p++) {
        var stickerId = my_orders[i].products[p].meta[0].value;
        if (fs.existsSync('/mypath/test')) {
        } else {
            exportedThisPdf = false;
        }
    }
    if (exportedThisPdf == true) {
        var data = {
            status: 'processing'
        };
        client.updateStatus(orderId, data, function (err) {
            if (err) console.log(err);
        })
    } else {
        var data = {
            status: 'failed'
        };
        client.updateStatus(orderId, data, function (err) {
            if (err) console.log(err);
        })
    }
}

console.log("callback");
```

I would now like to only continue the code once all my order statuses have been successfully updated to either processing or failed.

Is there a way to go about this problem in a clean, asynchronous way? 
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to await some promises. So at first create a global variable:

```
var promises = [];
```

Then basically whenever we do sth asynchronous, we add a promise to that array, e.g.:

```
promises.push(new Promise(function(resolve){
  client.updateStatus(orderId, data, function (err) {
        if (err) return console.log(err);
        resolve();
  })
}));
```

Then if all promises are added, we can await them:

```
Promise.all(promises)
.then(function(){
  console.log("finished");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try for this: Use Async Module

```
    var async = require('async');

    async.eachSeries(my_orders, function(order, ordercallback){

       async.eachSeries(order.products, function(product,  productcallback){
          // DO your put logic here

             client.updateStatus(orderId, data, function (err) {
                productcallback();
               })
       }, function(err){
        if(!err) ordercallback()
       });

     });
```

Comment: why to use async while we can use promise